# Lumia 520 Conference Call

Tags: lumia-520

According to the documentation, the conference call feature should work on Lumia 520.

However, while Add Call feature works and I call the other person, the Merge Calls button seems to do nothing - clicking it should merge both calls but does nothing.

The same feature works like a charm on the other Lumia I have access to, the 925. Both work with the same mobile operator.

Is this an issue with this particular model (520?), this particular phone or it just doesn't work on 520 even though the docs says it should work?

Comment: I have Lumia 520 and conference calling does work for me.

Comment: Maybe something carrier specific. Have you tried change the SIM used in the 520 with the one in 925?

Comment: @VitorCanova: no, I haven't, although this could be one of last resorts to try. Both SIM cards are from the same mobile operator and were issues like 2 weeks one after the other, this is why I haven't suspected the SIM card.

Comment: @WiktorZychla it could be that the feature is only enabled on one of the lines (SIMs), and a quick switch should confirm or deny...

Comment: Its a network dependent feature.

Comment: @Giri: I would say say however I made an experiment with switching sim cards and it works or not depending on the sim, both are in the same network of the same operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need 50 reputations to comment on that. So, I'm writing here...

So it worked when you tried with a different SIM right?? So its clear that its not your phone's problem :).The call conferencing is a feature that is given to a subscriber. May be the SIM you've tried, will have that feature. That's why its worked. Could you check to your local carrier customer care and verify the same?

Some carriers need a specific request for these extra features.

Comment: You got an accepted answer from me so that you will be able to comment other responses from now on ;)

Comment: Thanks. Did you try contacting the local carrier support?